Is there a faster way to evaluate the determinant of a $5\times 5$ matrix?

Evaluate det$(A)$ by a cofactor expansion along a row or column of your choice.

$$A=
\begin{bmatrix}
2 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
3 & 3 & 3 & -1 & 0 \\
1 & 3 & 4 & 2 & 3 \\
5 & 3 & 7 & 2 & 3 \\
2 & 3 & 4 & 2 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
My solution:
I understand that I can take remove the uppermost row and leftmost column for cofactor expansion, and work with that. That will leave me with:
$$2
\begin{vmatrix}
3 & 3 & -1 & 0\\ 
3 &4  &2  &3 \\ 
 3&  7& 2 &3 \\ 
 3&4  &2  &0 
\end{vmatrix}
-
\begin{vmatrix}
3 & 3 & 3 & 0\\ 
1 &3  &4  &3 \\ 
 5&  3& 7 &3 \\ 
 2&3 &4  &0 
\end{vmatrix}.
$$
And then I'll have to do some method for finding the det of those smaller matrices. But is there a faster way to do this, that isn't so time-consuming and annoying??

Apologies for bad formatting - I tried my best and this is my first time writing matrix in Latex.

I think in your solution matrices are two typos in the last cell should be a 0 and not a 3. And then your are left with two zeros in the last column. Apply the Leibnitz rule again and then your are left with four 3x3 matrices. Apply Sarrus rule and Voilà.

You can also try to bring it in row-echelon form.

arguably the most time-efficient way is to do row operations

I see. I'm just shooting ideas out there, but Is there perhaps anyway i can get the matrices into a triangular matrix form? or would that be redundant?

Hint: does adding or subtracting rows change the determinant?

If all you're allowed to do is expansion by cofactors then what you're doing is about as good as you can hope for. But usually row (or column) ops will help speed that up.

Alternating row operations and column operations, all integer coefficients leads fairly quickly to an obvious determinant. With extra care, this is how one reaches the Smith Normal Form, which is diagonal.
